# Could someone explain me the concecpt of "Recursion" in the context of the FORFILE Command (batch)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

i'm having some trouble to understand the concept of recursion while reading the explanation for the FORFILE command.

for the parameter /s it says in the reference:

> /s: Instructs the forfiles command to search into subdirectories
>   recursively.

**if i have hundreds of sub and subsubfolders what does recursion now mean?**
**Does the command start at root and goes than one level down, then the next and so on, or does it start at bottom going up one level etc.?**

Reference for forfiles can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Greetings!

Comment: From my past use of forfile it will go root\ root\subfolder1\ root\subfolder1\subsubfolder1\ root\subfolder1\subsubfolder2\ root\subfolder1\subsubfolder3\ ..... etc. So will drop down to first subfolder on each folder until the last available and then work through them as and when it comes across them...

Comment: So if i have a command like: 
forfiles /p "x:\test" /s /d -42 /c "CMD /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @File  /s /q"
The process goes like this?:
1. go to subfolder1 as long till you reach bottom
2. When reached bottom start moving up and deleting folders which are older than 42 days?
Because that would be pretty unefficient to go through all the files when in the end the folder is deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way recusion works is that is ensures that everything beneath a root folder is also worked on.  For example - if you have a C:\myfolder folder with a dozen subfolders, some of which have their own subfolders and even some of them do as well - each with files in... then managing them and applying a change to them all is very time consuming and easy to mess up without recursion.

Recurstion goes down a tree of folders by following 1 path right down to the bottom, then going up a level and going down again until it has to work back to the top and take the next branch.  EG:

it will work its way down to C:\folder\subfolder1\subsubfolder1\ and then do subsubfolder2.. when its finished that branch, it will go back up to C:\folder\subfolder2\ and work through that branch... eventually it will finish on C:\folder* and will progress onto C:\folder2..

Wow, this is tough to exaplin.  Essentially, it goes alphabetically as far down the first chain that it can, then hops up 1 level and repeats.  Eventually it has to hop up 2 levels and then goes again.. over and over until it has to jump back to the top

Comment: Good explanation, your right its tough to explain I tried in my comment but you made it sound a lot better!

Comment: best I could do without another coffee

Comment: Didn't update page just saw your comment. Thx think i got that now. As already postet the other answer:
So if i have a command like: forfiles /p "x:\test" /s /d -42 /c "CMD /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @File /s /q" The process goes like this?: 1. go to subfolder1 as long till you reach bottom 2. When reached bottom start moving up 1 Level and deleting folders which are older than 42 days? Because that would be pretty unefficient to go through all the files when in the end one folder could be deleted because of age and you didn't have to go through all the thousands of sub and subsub folders..

Comment: Thats the way it works.  It may seem unefficient at times, but it works, works well and is the way the windows OS has used recursion for decades now.  If my answer provided the information you needed - please click the tick button next to it and accept it as your answer.

Comment: I was and i have ;) No Tanks for your answer and your good help Sir!

Comment: Not sure which was the best one to comment back on... I can see where your coming from with the inefficiency however you have to remember that (forfiles /p "x:\test" /s /d -42 /c "CMD /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @File /s /q) is split to two parts the forfiles section simply gathers all files and folder older than 42 days not knowing what you want to do with this information then the CMD finishes the job so if you wanted to you can be more particular and not touch the folder in which case if Forfiles only done folders not files you would not have that granularity. :)

Comment: Hi Charles, i totally agree that the command has 2 parts, which cause this. But i'm not sure if i know what you mean with "be more particular". The only thing i could think of is to leave /s out, which is only possible when the interesting files/folders are in root...